# Remove Ubuntu from Meizu Pro 5

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android, phone

I bought a Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu edition. I love the phone, but Ubuntu touch isn't what I thought it would be. The App Store is lacking many popular apps.  I contacted Meizu and they said the phone could not be dual booted with Flyme or any other os software. I need to remove Ubuntu from the phone and install Flyme.  There are apps I need for work and this is my only option. Please guide me in the right direction or help me install android apps to my Ubuntu phone, if possible.

Thank you

Comment: Well, AFAIK there're different projects to run Android apps on GNU/Linux. «Shashlik» is to name one. Unfortunately I don't have Ubuntu phone to try something, but I think you could give a try to such projects to run Android apps.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I don't think Android app run under Ubuntu touch. Android is based on Linux, but it's completely different

Comment: @Motte001 why not? There're projects specifically to run Android apps on GNU/Linux distros. Like Wine to run Windows apps. And yes, I know both that Android is Linux based, and that Android have completely different architecture of GNU/Linux distros. But Android apps mostly compiled into Java bytecode, so assuming one could execute it, and have its API implemented, they'd work.

Comment: @Hi-Angel is it real java? I've heard it runs in the Dalvik-VM, something java like

Comment: @Motte001 it is java bytecode. It might not even have API of Java standard, but is irrelevant to my comment.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. I unfortunately am not a developer in anyway. I have been reading article after article and web searching until my eyes hurt. I think the only to get my monies worth is install android on the phone. Flyme is Meizu's version of android. I contacted the company, they said I would be able to install flyme, but they didn't have instructions on how to do so. Basically I got the brush off. If you can point me in the right direction I would be very greatful

Answer (score 0):

I have found the next information about it:

[How To] From Ubuntu to Android - Meizu 5 Pro
http://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/how-to/how-to-ubuntu-to-android-meizu-5-pro-t3395995/

[How To] From Android to Ubuntu - Meizu 5 Pro
http://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/how-to/how-to-android-to-ubuntu-meizu-5-pro-t3396191

Pro 5 ubuntu edition system dump and flashing Flyme on it...
http://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/help/pro-5-ubuntu-edition-dump-flashing-flyme-t3384860

I hope they were helpful for you.