# Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu edition dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch

I bought the Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu edition (international). I do like the OS, but the App Store is missing apps that are necessary for me, so I would like to know how to dual-boot Ubuntu Touch and any android firmware (CM, Flyme, etc).

Comment: I would like to congratulate you on the fact that you have a Pro 5. Wish I could get my hands on one. I am not sure if you can dual boot, but I would imagine you can. What paps are misssing for you as new onea are appearing every day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Ubuntu from Meizu Pro 5](http://askubuntu.com/questions/783110/remove-ubuntu-from-meizu-pro-5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support)